# How to do multiple SUM statements in a single SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sum

I'm pretty new to SQL and I need to figure out how to run multiple sums in the same statement.  For example, imagine you have a table something like this...

```
+----+---------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| id | name          | order_num   | cost       | company   |
+----+---------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
|  1 | John Smith    |           0 |      10.00 |  CompanyA |
|  2 | Sally Thomas  |           1 |      38.00 |  CompanyA |
|  2 | Sally Thomas  |           2 |      12.00 |  CompanyA |
|  1 | John Smith    |           3 |      19.00 |  CompanyA |
|  2 | Jimmy John    |           4 |      40.00 |  CompanyB |
+----+---------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
```

I would like to write a query that returns the name and total sum spent for each customer at CompanyA.  So basically...

```
+---------------+------------+
| name          | total      |
+---------------+------------+
| John Smith    |      29.00 |
| Sally Thomas  |      50.00 |
| Jimmy John    |       0.00 |
+---------------+------------+
```

To do that I know I'm going to need to use the sum function.  But everything I've tried so far results in summing up the entire column rather than the individual parts for each person.  This is just a simplified example of the bigger table I'm doing this on, so I don't know any of the field data beforehand.  How can I do multiple sums in one query to get this result?  Thanks!

Also, I'm using MySQL if it matters.

Comment: Edit your question and show what you have tried.  This looks like a basic `GROUP BY` query.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want:

```
select name, sum(case when company = 'CompanyA' then cost else 0 end) as Total
from t
group by name;
```